# Can i change a requested uri with a parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my controller code

public ActionResult Category(int id)
        {

```
        List<Category> category = new List<Category>();
        string text = string.Empty;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:49210/api/campaign/campaigncategory/id");
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                category = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Category>>(text);

            }

            return View(category);


        }
```

i have included the id in a URL but the passing value in id isn't changing the URL is there any possible way to do that ?

Comment: You are using the string `id` in your URL. Use the variable. `"http://localhost:49210/api/campaign/campaigncategory/" + id`

Comment: Thank you worked :)